# Default values to field collection module

Tags: entities

I have a field_collection, with:

> taxonomy select - number(price) - and Rating

[image: http://www.drupal.ru/files/1_225.jpg]

To add a value, you have to click the "add more" button.

Is there any way to do it simpler, or at least to set default values?